# svn: externals history with parent repository in redmine

Tags: svn, redmine, svn-externals

Setting ups some bug tracking with Redmine and svn. We have one app which has a collection of smaller apps within that are stored in different svn repos, so we have svn: externals controlling the group of them into one checkout. This also allows us to tie the main svn checkout within Redmine.

The thing is that the history reported to Redmine seems to only be the parent repository and does not include any of the svn:externals.

Looking to see if anyone knows of a way we can have Redmine see the history on all of the svn:externals as well.

Comment: Duplicate on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/290836/svn-externals-history-with-parent-repository-in-redmine